# Raspberry pi 2 won't boot what did i do wrong?

Tags: raspbian

My raspberry pi has raspbian lite installed on it. I log in and it just stays with the warranty message and then has the places to input code. it then does not boot up the raspbian desktop. I have tried rebooting the pi but it does not work.

Comment: if you can log in, the pi works :p

Comment: Raspbian Lite does not have a desktop - it is command line only.  The two other images from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ (both saying **with dektop**) will give you a gui.

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian Buster Lite does not contain a desktop environment.

You need to flash Rasbian Buster with Desktop.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/